# Array gets overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**Background:** I have a function that takes an array of local link strings, loads each link and finds all of the `<a>` tags from a specific location in each link, then pushes each tag's `href` attribute into an array called `results`.

**The Problem:** The results array is empty after the function has finished running. If I test the array's length or content with `console.log` inside of the `.load()` function, the array has content, as I would expect; outside of that function however, the array is empty.

**Hypothesis:** I think that the populated array is somehow getting overwritten by the empty array, but I can't see how that is happening. I even tried placing the result array outside of the main function, as a global variable, but still it is empty after the function has executed.

**Function**

```
function collectAllTrailLinks(arrayOfSections){
   var result = [];
   var len = arrayOfSections.length;
   $("body").append("<div id='placeHolder'></div>");

   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var params = arrayOfSections[i] + " " + "blockquote a";
      $("#placeHolder").load(params, function(){
        $("#placeHolder a").each(function(){
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            if (link !== "symbols.html") {
                result.push(link);
            }
         });
     }); 
   }
   console.log(result.length);
   //return result;
}
```

**Function Call**

```
function ctRunAll(){
  createTable("#ctSection h1", 16);
  var sectionLinks = collectLinks(hikingContent);
  collectAllTrailLinks(sectionLinks[0]);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Is the "if (link !== "symbols.html")" condition ever met?

Comment: what is the length of the arrayOfSections, is it even going into your loop?

Comment: *If I test the array's length or content with console.log inside of the .load() function, the array has content*. So I think yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the callback function passed to `$("#placeHolder").load()` is executed asynchronously. Which means that function `collectAllTrailLinks()` is already finished before the first call to that callback is taking place.

What you can do is return a promise so you can wait until all loads are finished. I've created a code snippet that demonstrates the native [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) way (simplified with `setTimeout` instead of `$.load`)

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function collectAllTrailLinks() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var index = i;
            setTimeout(function() {
                output.innerHTML += 'finished ' + index + ' ';
             resolve('result of ' + index);
         }, i * 200);
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

collectAllTrailLinks().then(function (result) {
    output.innerHTML += '<br /><br />All done: ' + JSON.stringify(result);
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JQuery Deferred way**

```
function collectAllTrailLinks(arrayOfSections) {
   var defer = $.Deferred();
   var result = [];
   var len = arrayOfSections.length;
   var finishedLoads = 0;
   $("body").append("<div id='placeHolder'></div>");

   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var params = arrayOfSections[i] + " " + "blockquote a";
      $("#placeHolder").load(params, function(){
        $("#placeHolder a").each(function(){
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            if (link !== "symbols.html") {
                result.push(link);
            }
         });
         finishedLoads++;
         if (finishedLoads == len) {
             defer.done(result); // mark deferred as done (will resolve promise)
         }
     }); 
   }
   return defer.promise(); // return promise where you can wait on
}

// Usage (wait for promise)
collectAllTrailLinks(arrayOfSections).done(function(result) {
   console.log(result.length);
});
```

**Native Promise way**

```
function collectAllTrailLinks(arrayOfSections) {
   var promises = [];

   $("body").append("<div id='placeHolder'></div>");

   for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfSections.length; i++) {
       var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          var params = arrayOfSections[i] + " " + "blockquote a";
          $("#placeHolder").load(params, function(response, status, xhr) {
             if (status === "error") {
                 return reject(response);
             }

             var result = [];
             $("#placeHolder a").each(function() {
                var link = $(this).attr("href");
                if (link !== "symbols.html") {
                   result.push(link);
                }
             });

             resolve(result);
          });
       });
       promises.push(promise);
   }

   return Promise.all(promises);
}

// Usage
collectAllTrailLinks(arrayOfSections).then(function(results) {
   console.log(results.length);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I tried your JQuery method but unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting the usage to work properly. I've updated my question to reflect my original function call implementation.